# Safari anchors on links not working

Tags: html, xhtml, safari

My html anchor is as follows.

```
<a name="template-8"/>
<h4 class="template" id="template-8">A title</h4>
```

As far as I know the browser should skip to the element with a matching name or id attribute.

When I type in the url http://my.site.com/templates#template-8 safari jumps down the page as expected.

However when linking as below the anchor does nothing. Chrome, Opera, IE7 and Firefox all work.

```
<a href="http://my.site.com/templates#template-8">A link</a>
```

Safari is version 5.0, could this be a safari bug?

Comment: Why would you write anchor elements as `<a name="target-id" />` instead of `<a href="#target-id">Target ID</a>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was I had a redirect header in the page I was linking to.

Opera, IE, Chrome, Firefox will carry over the anchor to the new page. However safari loses the anchor on the redirect.

If you are having trouble with safari anchors disable any redirects.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. I experienced the issue in Wordpress. I am not exactly sure why there was a redirect happening. Maybe I renamed the page at some point and did not update the in-page links.

Answer (score 13):

For me, I simply had to change

```
http://domain.com/page#myanchor
```

to

```
http://domain.com/page/#myanchor
```

Comment: Cheers for this. Simple fix and works in Firefox, Opera and Chrome as well.

Comment: Really? This works for you in Safari? I don't see the same behavior.

Comment: This is an implementation of Keyo's answer - it works by removing the redirect caused by omitting the trailing slash (at least it does in wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue and found your post while searching - obviously you've fixed this since it was back in 2010 and but figured I would post what I found in case someone else finds this. :)

I'm using htaccess to redirect my url from mydomaincom/index.php to mydomaincom/ and found that my nav didn't work in Safari since my href addresses where index.php#value and Safari v5 wouldn't carry over the anchor links.

Rather than turn off my redirect I just changed the urls to point to mydomaincom/#value.  Not only did this work great for all browsers but it also made my page quicker (not yet sure how but will search this now :))

Answer (score 1):

There are two side issues I see, which aren't the cause (since you found the problem already) but probably don't help:

- Self-closing `<a>` tag. You can't self-close tags that are supposed to have end tags, it should be: `<a name="template-8"></a>`.
- The `name` and `id` attributes share the same "namespace", so you cannot have the same value for a `name` and `id` attribute. All browsers from the past 10 years support anchors on IDs, so scrap that useless link tag.

Answer (score 0):

It has not worked with the previously proposed solutions, it has worked for me to create a redirection using javascript in the following way.

```
<!-- <a href="#first-block"> -->
<a href="javascript:redirection('first-block')">

function redirection(destination){
    window.location.href = "example.com/page.html#" + destination;
}
```

I leave it here in case someone serves you in the future.

Answer (score -2):

To fix an anchor tag in Safari. I proceed this way :

```
 <a href="#" class="btn">A tag</a>
```

And on my css file :

```
.btn{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

The important thing is for some reason, sometimes Safari needs to see your link as a block, and it can be useful if you create a list, with some links inside. 
Example :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn">A tag</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn">A tag</a></li>
</ul>
```

Works for Safari 6+