# django and angular url patterns

Tags: django, angularjs

Sometimes in my code I pass get parameters with URL's. One particular scenario is if the user is not logged in, but puts a URL for a page that requires login, they will be required to login first.

In that case I may have a URL such as: `www.example.com/home/#/main/`.

The end of the URL `/#/main/` is for angular. However, in django when I do the below to get the `next` parameter above, I do this:

```
self.request.GET.get('next', self.redirect_url)
```

The problem is that in this case, `next` provides everything but the angular portion, so I get: `www.example.com/home/`.

Is there anyway to get the remaining portion of the URL as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to urlencode the url before you add it as a parameter. Then it will turn into %23 and insn't the separator for the anchor anymore, which is handled client side only as KVISH described.

Comment: How do you url encode when the login is handled by the framework?

Comment: If you rely on the framework to make an unauth redirect there is no way to do that. If you pass the URL in a get parameter you have to use urlencode() yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly you can't. Django doesn't even see the anchor, its all handled on client (browser).

[How to identify an anchor in a url in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885023/how-to-identify-an-anchor-in-a-url-in-django)

The way I got around this is I use jQuery to set a hidden input field to the hash location, which can be obtained like so:

```
window.location.hash
```

The hash gets submitted with the form and I can take it from there.