# Express Node.js get originalurl with special symbols "#"

Tags: node.js, rest, url, express, get

I have a GET REST endpoint:

```
router.get('/test/*', function(req, res) {
    var test = req.originalUrl;
}
```

it doesn't return the full url when I have "#" sign in them:

ie:

/test/asf#23

I want "asf#23", but the above code gives me only "asf". Thoughts?

Edit:
req.originalUrl, req.path, req.baseUrl, req.url all return the same thing. Any other ideas?

Edit 2:
I have absolutely no control over the client, I simply need to print out the url the client tried to access. Is there a way do parse it?

Comment: Do you try `req.path` or `req.baseUrl`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because hash part is not considered as a part of URI and so it is not passed to the server at all.
You can make it URI part by requesting `/test/asf?id=23` for example. In this case, you will be able to get this `id` by addressing `req.query.id`.

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I cannot change the client's uri pattern, I just need to parse what they're trying to access, is there a way?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there is not. And again, this is not Express who doesn't  support it, but the browser who doesn't pass it.

Answer (score -1):

`#` is unsafe to be used in a url, guess that is the reason it is not being parsed

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I cannot change the client's uri pattern, I just need to parse what they're trying to access, is there a way? I'm sure "#" isn't too uncommon in urls, express simply doesn't support it?

Comment: @user3586553 to answer your question, I don't think express allows you to send anchors or anchor links or urls to the server from the client. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885023/how-to-identify-an-anchor-in-a-url-in-django