# How to read values from a redirect url in Django Python

Tags: python, django

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8084/Happy/studen/#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1
```

I have a recirect url like this which redirects to a handler in my django app and it works fine .

The issue um facing was to read values appearing after # in the particular url . 
How may I read those values in the corresponding handler?

This is a pure Django Python Implementation and there wont be any javascripts to identify any urls

I cannot change the behavior of the token coming with the #

I Have tried both of these ways

```
  n = request.get_full_path()

  k = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
```

But it wont give me the values after #
Is there a specific way to do this in django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify an anchor in a url in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885023/how-to-identify-an-anchor-in-a-url-in-django)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler This is a pure Django Python Implementation and there wont be any javascripts to identify any urls 

I cannot change the behavior of the token coming with the #

Comment: Read the linked question's answers, there is no token coming with the # - it does not get sent to the server. Open Chrome, press F12 for the developer tools, go to the 'Network' tab, and watch as you visit something like `https://www.example.com/test?querystring=true#thisword` - the Request Headers include `test?querystring=true` and do not include `#thisword`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler this comes from Fitbit API , i have no control over it , they are explicitly saying Note: When using the Authorization Code Grant Flow, Fitbit will also append #_=_ at the end of your redirect URI upon success  https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/

Comment: @Kalanamith They are not visible to Django. The browsers do not send those to the web server. You can only inspect them on the client side, using JS, for example.

Comment: Judging by [this introduction to Oauth2](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified), you are trying to use the [browser based app](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified#browser-based-apps) approach `#token=ACCESS_TOKEN - At this point, some Javascript code can pull out the access token`, but you need to be using the [web-server-apps](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified#web-server-apps) approach `the service redirects the user back to your site with an auth code [querystring] ?code=AUTH_CODE_HERE`. (no idea if the FitBit API supports this)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thank you for your link , it was really helpful