# Appended anchor link is not active on Safari / iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I've got a function, used by a lot of different parts of my site which calls a confirmation box. When it's called it formats the box with the various elements and appends it to the body, like so...

```
$('body').append("<div id=\"confirmation\"><a href=\"javascript:confirmed()\">confirmed</a> <a href=\"javascript:closeConfirm()\">cancel</a></div>");
```

Now, this works perfectly for everything accept the iPhone Safari browser, which doesn't seem to activate, or load the anchor into the DOM properly... **it is not clickable**. This is the problem, tho the box appears correctly, touching the anchor does nothing. Console.log proves this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you cut and paste your exact code? The sample provided won't even run, because of the unescaped double-quotes.

Comment: try this - `$('body').html($('body').html() + <div id=\"confirmation\"><a href=\"javascript:confirmed()\">confirmed</a> <a href=\"javascript:closeConfirm()\">cancel</a></div>");`

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to a new page ?
Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working

Comment: Jaery, that doesn't work at all. And Alytrem, thanks - relevant but not the case this time... I've tried with a simple alert() call as well, so no page linking. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very particular situation was solved by moving the anchor so it ***did not*** overlay an embedded video. When the anchor was placed over the embedded video on the iPhone - touch events above it were disregarded in favour of the *touch to take to quicktime and play video event*.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing

```
$div = $('<div>', { id : "confirmation"});
$aConfirmed =  $('<a>', { href : "#", class : "confirmed", text: "confirmed"});
$aCancel =  $('<a>', { href : "#", class : "cancel", text: "Cancel"});
$div.append($aConfirmed).append($aCancel);
$('body').append($div);
```

And then use some event handlers like (this assumes jQuery > 1.7

```
$(document).on("click", "a.confirmed", function(){
   confirmed();
});

$(document).on("click", "a.cancel", function(){
   closeConfirm();
});
```

Comment: The problem is, I pass arguments to confirmed() that change depending on what's needed. I've also tried not calling confirmed at all, just calling alert() and nothing on iPhone.

Comment: @waxical what i was trying to say is: "don't use inline javascript", use event handlers

Comment: Ok - I've tried it and no avail. But, I've discovered the problem. The confirmation box is overlaying a Quicktime video embed - on iPhone - this seems to disable touch events over the top as I place links below it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something other than an anchor tag for testing and see if that works.

Comment: ok cool, what I meant was attach the event to something other than an <a></a> tag.
How did the alert work for you?