# Hashlink is not working in Safari

Tags: html, wordpress, browser, safari

While using haslink (#testhash) is not working on Safari. I am really unable to locate the problem.
Here is the following code I am providing below

```
<a href="?page_id=112#testhash">Click here to go to Hash</a>

<div style="height:500px">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="testhash"></div>
<div>............Test Data............</div>
```

When I am clicking on the link, it is got going to proper place on Safari but it is working fine on Google Chrome, Mozila Firefox and IE9. In Safari the link is redirect to the site `http://example.com/` instead `http://example.com/#testhash` after URL rewritting. The funny thing is when I am directly putting the link `http://example.com/#testhash` on the address bar of Safari, it is working fine but the time of clicking it is not working and also when I am writting `http://example.com/?page_id=112#testhash`, it is giving problem.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working) might help.

Comment: No It didn't help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do one thing. Give the full link instead of `?page_id` because sometime Safari or some other browsers write different rewrite rules for Wordpress and thats why Hashlinks doesn't work. You may put

`<a href="http://testwordpress.com/[*rewritten Page By Browser]/#testhash">Click here to go to Hash</a>`
instead of 
`<a href="?page_id=112#testhash">Click here to go to Hash</a>` and it may work.

*I meant by Rewritten page as the browser divides the page by parents and children like `about-us/page/etc` so the url should be from my example `http://testwordpress.com/about-us/page/etc/#testhash`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the href to just "#testhash" and see if that fixes your problem?

Editing my answer as it wasn't clear:

Try this:

```
<a href="#testhash">Click here to go to Hash</a>

<div style="height:1200px">&nbsp;</div>
<a name="testhash" />
<div id="testhash"></div>
```

Comment: I changed it already and gave a different name as #soumyahash. But it is still same

Comment: Edited my answer can you see if this helps you now?