# Safari Overshoots on Links to Named Anchors

Tags: html, safari

My website utilizes links to named anchor tags. Here's an example:

```
<a class="thislevel" href="#1">blah blah blah</a>
```

And then further down the page:

```
<a class="subtitle" name="1">[3.OA.A.1]</a>
```

Here is the link to the actual page:
http://mathcorestandards.org/k-8/3rd-grade/3-oa-a/

In Chrome and Firefox the links work as intended and take you to the subtitle, but in Safari the links takes you a little past the correct spot on the page to where you can't actually see the subtitle.

Here is a link to the only thing similar on Stack Overflow that I've found, but I don't think I'm having the same issue:
[Safari anchors on links not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working)

I have tried switching from name to id with no luck. I have also investigated and I don't think it's a CSS issue.

Is this a Safari bug?

Thanks for your help. This is the first question I've ever asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Safari 5.1.7 under Windows; it behaves just like the others. Don't have a Mac to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a Safari on Mac peculiarity. I tested it on other browsers and the same behavior did not appear. Thanks to Mr Lister for checking Safari on Windows.