# Anchors with # in my navigation are not working consistently?

Tags: jquery, html, url-rewriting

I have the following issue.
In the main navigation of my website (visible from most pages) I have 3 links pointing to different sections of the same page.

```
http://www.example.com/brokerdefense/nos-services/
http://www.example.com/brokerdefense/nos-services/#forfait
http://www.example.com/brokerdefense/nos-services/#alacarte
```

The anchors are pointing to sections (div) of the page which have id attributes (they are unique I have double-checked this).

If I copy/paste these URLs to my browsers navigation bar they all work fine and point to the expected section of the page. However when I click on the third link in my navigation the browser always refreshes the page.

The 3 links are in the exact context. They follow each other and have the same form li > a in the same ul.

```html
....
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/whereever/">Some link to another page</a>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/otherpage/">Link to the page</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/nos-services/">Link to the page WITHOUT anchor</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/nos-services/#forfait">Link to the page WITH anchor that works fine</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/nos-services/#alacarte">Second Link to the page WITH anchor than does not work properly</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
....
<div id="forfait">
....
</div>
<div id="alacarte">
....
</div>
```

MAC OS X 10.10.5
On Safari Version 10.0 (10602.1.50.0.10)
The anchors get stripped off.
The page is opened but not at the beginning not in the expected section of the page.

On Firefox 50.0.2
The page gets reloaded (third link but not second) but points in the proper section of the page.

Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)
Same behavior as Firefox

Windows ?
IE (unconfirmed version on clients computer) apparently behaves the same as Safari.

Any clues about what is going on ? Could it be related to rewrite rules used on the website ? JS related ?

Thanks for your answers.

Edit : 
It might be related to the question I found below.
[Safari anchors on links not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working?rq=1)
It says that it might related to some form of redirection created by Wordpress. Since I am also using Wordpress that might be a possible cause of the problem. But it does not solve my problem. Why does the first link work and not the second one ?

Comment: Hi Olivier and welcome. Please could you post some HTML that illustrates the problem. You will get a answer much more quickly if you provide more detail.

Comment: Hi I am bit relunctant publicly give the address a website still in development. However I would rather give it privately if I knew how.

Comment: That is understandable but posting a link to your site is not optimal anyway. What you need to do is take the guts of the issue out and make a minimal example with html, css and any script that illustrates the issue. Then you might get some responses. Your question is now 13 hours old and it is virtually unheard of to have so few comments or proposed answers for that long IF you provide a working sample.  Search for `how to ask a question in stack overflow` and you will see the point. If you can use the scriptlet option in the question editor or provide a Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I edited the question and added code that seemed relevant, and helpful to help clarify my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Olivier - if question 3020456 worked for you then why not either flag your question as a duplicate of it or better create an answer (answer your own question), explain that you found that earlier question and what you did to solve your issue. Who knows, maybe you will need than answer again one day.

Comment: No to did not work for me. It only provides me with a potential explanation as to why it is happening but in no way did it give me a solution.

Comment: Reading that other question, there seems to be issues with properly formed html, such as closing anchors correctly. This may not be directly appropriate to your issue but it tells me that we are not going to be able to answer this quickly without getting involved in looking at your entire code. Like I said, you need to cut this down to the smallest possible set of code that illustrates the issue. Without that you are going nowhere.