# Anchor Links in Safari...?

Tags: html, css, safari, anchor

Hi cant seem to get my Anchor links working in Safari...

```
  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="resources.html#copy" target="_top">Resources</a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html#copy" target="_top">Contact</a> </li>
```

I have a bunch of links that go to their respective pages and then should drop down to the "copy" anchor but this doesn't work in safari...

As you can see I've specified a target which i was told should help... I have tried changing my links to "page.html/#copy" but this doesn't work. i have also used ID as name is no longer used in html 5.

my anchor looks like this...

```
<h1 id="copy" class="-white">.</h1>
```

class just makes the text white so cant see the '.' on the page.

```
.-white{
color: #FFF;}
```

im assuming it's something simple and I've just been staring at this to long to see it...

Thank you

Comment: The id you used, 'copy' is unique on the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: yep there is only one ID="copy" on each page.  

In safari if i click the link it takes me to the page but dosnt scroll down to the section. however if i click the link a 2nd time it scrolls me down...

Comment: When you click the link in Safari, after the new page is loaded, is the #copy part still in the url or not?

Comment: yes the address bar shows the #copy at the end of all the links just doesn't go down to it.

Comment: Does it work if you use `href="contact/#copy"` instead?

Comment: nope this just takes me to what looks like a "basic html text" version of the page with no styling on.

Comment: How are you testing this site? Is it just html files in a local folder, or is this on a server? Maybe there is a redirect involved. I have problems reproducing this issue locally. On a side note, you should be able to drop the '.' and the css to make it invisible by using this instead: `<h1 id="copy" class="-white">&nbsp;</h1>`

Comment: testing locally and on a server works fine in everything but safari. is there a way to fix safari redirecting?

Comment: I was thinking it could be related to this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working), but if you have the same problem locally it must be something different. Does the anchor work if you enter the absolute url?