# Is there a way to use anchor links in SVG on IOS?

Tags: ios, svg, hyperlink, anchor

I have an SVG of the US states, and need anchor links to scroll to the state info on the page below.  The anchors work fine on desktop and android, but not on IOS. The state changes to to hover color when clicked and does not link, and the hover color remains.

I found some suggestions to use xlink:href, but that is depreciated.  I did try it to see if it worked and it did not.  I have also tried some suggestions providing jquery code, but it did not work and also stopped the links from working on desktop.

The SVG is set up with hrefs wrapping each path like this:

```
    <svg viewbox="0 0 959 593"> <a href="#ak"> <path id="AK" ..."> 
    <title>Alaska</title></path></a>
```

(I've removed the long string of code for the path)

Here is the link to the page with the map.  The anchor links work on desktop and android and not IOS:

https://www.automatictrap.com/pages/trappable-species

I have never posted here before, so I apologize if this is not enough info.

Comment: Please add SVG sample and what's your final expectation.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the URL with the map example to the original post.

Comment: You need to give safari support for Mac OS. Try for now `<a xlink:href="#ak">`

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply.  I read the xlink:href was depreciated, but it was one of the recommendations I tried.  Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: You can repost your question with title **Anchor not working for SVG in safari and iOS webView**. But before visit some similar questions may be anyone of them solves your issue. Here is one similar question. Ref this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. Some of the anchor links on iPhone only seem to work when "a id" is used, and the links from the SVG only work when "a name" is used.