# React - Anchor tags not working in Safari

Tags: reactjs

Cant figure out why my anchor tags are not working in Safari.  They work fine in Chrome and Firefox.
Im developing in React and with react-router.

```
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

My landing page contains my various components

```
 <SectionProject id="services"/>
 <SectionTeams id="aboutus"/>
```

Then my footer component contains the following

```
  <li>
    <a style={{ color: 'red' }} href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/#services">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/#aboutus">About Us</a>
  </li>
```

The links all work fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not safari.

Comment: Try with removing the slashes on the href `/#service` to `#service`

Comment: tried that and still works in other browsers but not in safari.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `Link` component from react-router instead of a tags? See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link. I would try something like: `<Link to={{ pathname: "/", hash: "#services", }} />`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work in either safari or Chrome. Weird.

Comment: what I also just noticed is that when I click on those links in Safari, it doesn't work when I click it, but if I copy and paste that link to a new windows it does work.

Comment: Have you tried any of those solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working