# Why my anchor link on shopify menu doesn't work on Safari?

Tags: safari, menu, shopify, anchor

I am using Shopify with PageFly builder and the issue is, that on Safari and iOS, all anchor links won't work. Even on Desktop or mobile.

I used all methods :

https//XXXXX/**#link**
**#link**
https://xxxxxx **#link**

On the first display, only one of the links works. Once the page is loaded and the link on the menu is clicked, none of them works.

Any ideas please ? I'm not a developer and i'm new on this platform.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working

Comment: Hello, i've already check this one. I don't understand what to do.

Comment: Anybody please... Help me. I'm very confused.